# Combine faceted plots with common facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p4 <- ggplot(data = df.2) +
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = TOTAL_ME/LOS, y = LOS, color = HC), alpha = 0.3, height = 0.2) +
  labs(color = "Treatment group",  
       x = "Morphine equivalents per day", 
       y = "Length of stay (days)",
       tag = "B") +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("EXPERIMENTAL", "HISTORICAL CONTROL"),
                       labels=c("Experimental", "Historical Control")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 4), xlim = c(0,50)) +
  geom_tile(data = means, mapping = aes(x = meMN, y = losMN, width = wid*2, height = hght*2,
                                        fill = HC), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(data = means, mapping = aes(x = meMN, y = losMN, color = HC), shape = 3) + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ PROC.FULL, labeller = labeller(PROC.FULL = label_wrap_gen(15)))

ggarrange(p3, p4, ncol=1, nrow=2, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")
```

`p3` is identical to the above plot, only `ggplot(data = df)`.

When `p3` and `p4` are combined, I obtain the following plot:

[image]

Ideally, I would like only one x axis along the bottom and only one facet labeling across the top. I tried to just remove the facet labels from `p4`, but this actually makes the size of the plots on the bottom row unequally large compared to the top row. I would like to add a label on the right side of the figure that labels the top row as `p3` and the bottom row as `p4`. It would be nice also to only have one Y axis label on the left that spans both rows. Essentially, I am looking to combine these two separate plots (which are produced from two different `data.frame`s) and remove as much redundant information as possible.

UPDATE: I have bound the data frames as suggested and this appears much closer. I still have the problem of redundant labels though. Also, I would prefer the facets to line up vertically ("Laparoscopic Roux-En-Y Gastric Bypass" should be one above the other) with the `id_col` labeled on the right side by row.

```
df.3 <- bind_rows(df, df.2, .id = "id_col")

ggplot(data = df.3) +
  geom_jitter(mapping = aes(x = TOTAL_ME/LOS, y = LOS, color = HC), alpha = 0.3, height = 0.2) +
  labs(color = "Treatment group",  
       x = "Morphine equivalents per day", 
       y = "Length of stay (days)",
       tag = "B") +
  scale_color_discrete(breaks=c("EXPERIMENTAL", "HISTORICAL CONTROL"),
                       labels=c("Experimental", "Historical Control")) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 4), xlim = c(0,50)) +
  geom_tile(data = means, mapping = aes(x = meMN, y = losMN, width = wid*2, height = hght*2,
                                        fill = HC), alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_point(data = means, mapping = aes(x = meMN, y = losMN, color = HC), shape = 3) + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~ id_col + PROC.FULL, labeller = labeller(PROC.FULL = label_wrap_gen(15)))
```

[image]

UPDATE2:

Fixed it! Just had to use `facet_grid`, not `facet_wrap`.

Comment: Combine `df` and `df.2` into a single dataframe, `purrr::bind_rows(df, df.2, .id = "id_col")` and then also facet by `id_col`.

Comment: Thanks, take a look at the update!

Comment: Try with `facet_wrap(id_col ~ PROC.FULL, ...)` (or the other way around as you like).

Comment: Thank you, figured that out right as you posted it!